# ansible - customize list content based on condtion in role default vars

Tags: ansible

I'm looking to defined a list of dict in the default main.yml of a role base on a condtion. Do You know how to do so?

I've tried that:

```
pkg: "[ 
{% if 'web' in group_names %}                                               
        { name: 'pkg-php' },                                                
        { name: 'pkg-web' },                                                
{% endif %}                                                                 
    { name: 'pkg-libs' },                                                   
    { name: 'pkg-core' } ]"
```

The issue of that, is that it returns a string not a list of dict

**Expecting output**

When host is in 'web' group:

```
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-php' }                                                
  - { name: 'pkg-web' }                                                
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }                                                   
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
```

When not:

```
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }                                                   
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little more verbose but why not just wrap the outer chunks?

```
{% if 'web' in group_names %}                                               
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-php' }                                                
  - { name: 'pkg-web' }                                                
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }                                                   
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
{% else %}
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }                                                   
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a correct syntax: 

The offending line appears to be:


{% if 'web' in group_names %}

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) it's not possible to conditionally include the role's default variables other than strings.

```
pkg: |
  {% if inventory_hostname in groups['web'] %}
  inventory_hostname IS member of the group 'web'
  {% else %}
  inventory_hostname IS NOT member of the group 'web'
  {% endif %}
```

There is the option to conditionally [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task). You might want to review [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and decide whether this fit potential other conditions of the project.

To proceed with *include_vars* put the variables into the files

```
$ cat vars/all.yml
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
$ cat vars/web.yml
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-php' }
  - { name: 'pkg-web' }
```

If the *inventory_hostname* (the host the play is applied to) is a member of the group *web* the variables from the file *vars/web.yml* are included. The play below

```
- hosts: srv-web-01
  vars:
    web:
      pkg: []
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: vars/all.yml
        name: common
    - include_vars:
        file: vars/web.yml
        name: web
      when: inventory_hostname in groups['web']
    - set_fact:
        pkg: "{{ pkg|default([]) + web.pkg + common.pkg }}"
    - debug:
        var: pkg
```

gives

```
"pkg": [
    {
        "name": "pkg-php"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "pkg-web"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "pkg-libs"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "pkg-core"
    }
]
```

**Standard solution**

Ansible standard solution to include variables for a group of hosts is [group_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) which are in the [Variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) right above *role defaults*. Expected output can be simply achieved with the following *group_vars*

```
$ cat group_vars/all.yml 
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
$ cat group_vars/web.yml 
pkg:
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
  - { name: 'pkg-php' }
  - { name: 'pkg-web' }
```

**Advanced solution**

It's not efficient to update many *group_vars* files if a common item changes. It is possible to declare modular group specific variables

```
$ cat group_vars/all.yml
pkg_all:
  - { name: 'pkg-libs' }
  - { name: 'pkg-core' }
$ cat group_vars/web.yml
pkg_web:
  - { name: 'pkg-php' }
  - { name: 'pkg-web' }
```

and concatenate all pkg_* in the host variables' space i.e the pkg_* variables declared in the *group_vars* the host is a member of

```
- set_fact:
    pkg: "{{ pkg|default([]) + lookup('vars', item) }}"
  loop: "{{  hostvars[inventory_hostname].keys()|
             select('match', '^pkg_(.*)$')|
             list }}"
- set_fact:
    pkg: "{{ pkg|unique }}"
- debug:
    var: pkg
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. But my issue is that I want to declare this list in a default/main.yml of a role, so we don't have to bother to define it in the inventory. So your proposal does fullfill completly my needs